# What is the derivative of $\ln\left(x^2 + (3/4)x\right)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> What is the derivative of $\ln\left(x^2 + (3/4)x\right)$?

I did $\dfrac{1}{\left(x^2 + (3/4)x\right)}$ and multiplied it by $(2x + 3/4)$

Is this right? Should I have flipped $3/4$ instead because it was being multiplied to the numerator which is $1$?

Comment: Yes, it is right. No, you need no flipping

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are correct.It's $$\frac {2x+\frac {3}{4}}{x^2+\frac {3x}{4}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the verification. I can never seem to format my texts like that. lol

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing pattern matching in your head in applying the chain rule, you can use the property of the logarithms:

$$\log\left(x^2 + \tfrac{3}{4}x\right)=\log\left(x\cdot\left(x + \tfrac{3}{4}\right)\right)=\log(x)+\log\left(x + \tfrac{3}{4}\right)$$

And then

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\log(x)+\log\left(x + \tfrac{3}{4}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x\ +\tfrac{3}{4}}$$

which you might rewrite by introducing the common denominator $x\cdot\left(x + \tfrac{3}{4}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is the product of $\frac{d}{dy}\ln(y)*\frac{d}{dx}y$ where $y=x^2+\frac{3}{4}x$, which is
$$\frac{1}{x^2+\frac{3}{4}x}\left(2x+\frac{3}{4}\right)$$